# Impact of support package for Android

Tags: android

What are some of the drawbacks of using support package for Android? 
How much does it impact the size of the application and possibly performance?

Thanks.

Comment: here's a drawback: you have to spend two minutes right clicking your project in Eclipse and selecting "Add Support Library"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage the support package gives you in terms of up-to-date UI design & additional ways to get your app more performant (i.e. Loaders) is way bigger than the 200kb or so additional data and about 0 performance loss.

If you want exact numbers try adding the compatibility package to some app.

Answer (score 1):

> How much does it impact the size of the application and possibly performance?

It does impact the size of your app but not that much if you consider *what you get in return*. There is no downside regarding the app performance in most cases (and if there were then they are frequently fixed in the revisions).

The Support Library is meant `to simplify your development by offering more APIs that you can bundle with your application so you can worry less about platform versions.` This - for example - will allow you to develop one APK for all version (instead of two) and yet have the ability to enjoy using the great UI additions introduced in later version of Android.